# How can I achieve something like the highlighted area below?

Tags: android, image

I have been trying to design something like this in android code but have not been able to. I have little android experience. You you be able to help me by posting the full code for how to be able to do this.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 2):

**Add** :

In your theme attribute:

```
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Then just put an imageview in a relativelayout and some text on and you're good to go!